# How to place tabs over JInternalFrame title bar in Java Swing?

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, jtabbedpane, jinternalframe

I want to have a JInternalFrame that will be able to handle JTabbedPane much like the Eclipse IDE. I want the tabs to sit on top of the title bar. Each tab should have its own close button. The InternalFrame should also have a close button so that a user can close all the tabs in one go.

This is what I have:

[image]

This is what I want to have (screenshot taken from Eclipse IDE):

[image]

I don't know how I can achieve this. Can anyone please point me in the right direction?

**EDIT:**

Based on a comment to look into UI Delegate, I created a UI delegate subclass that is able to remove the menu, but there are some problems with this:

1. It looks kind of funny in comparison to a normal JInternalFrame, even though I haven't done anything to it but comment out the "createActionMap" and "add(menuBar)" lines.

   [image]
2. I can't find anywhere in the library code to indicate how the title bar and contentPane positions are set - obviously I want to move the position of the contentPane to overlap the title bar.

Here are the codes:

```
public class MyInternalFrameUI extends BasicInternalFrameUI {

    public MyInternalFrameUI(JInternalFrame b) {
        super(b);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public static ComponentUI createUI(JComponent b)    {
        return new MyInternalFrameUI((JInternalFrame)b);
    }
    
    protected JComponent createNorthPane(JInternalFrame w) {
        titlePane = new MyBasicInternalFrameTitlePane(w);
        return titlePane;
      }
}

public class MyBasicInternalFrameTitlePane extends BasicInternalFrameTitlePane {

    public MyBasicInternalFrameTitlePane(JInternalFrame f) {
        super(f);
    }
    
    protected void installTitlePane() {
        installDefaults();
        installListeners();

        createActions();
        enableActions();
        //createActionMap(); // This method is package protected and not visible

        setLayout(createLayout());

        assembleSystemMenu();
        createButtons();
        addSubComponents();
    }
    
    protected void addSubComponents() {
        //add(menuBar); // Remove this to disable the menu
        add(iconButton);
        add(maxButton);
        add(closeButton);
    }
}
```

Comment: You will need to write your own internal frame look and feel delegate...

Comment: After countless hours of researching about LAF, this appears to be very complex for a simple requirement. I went through some of the library files, which caused even more confusion. Is it easiest to learn about Synth LAF? However, I don't want to have provide the LAF for ALL the components. Quote from wikipedia: However synth does not provide a default look, and components that are not defined in the synth XML file will not be painted. It is however possible to assign a default style to all other widgets, and customize styles for some specific widgets only. - But it doesn't explain how.

Answer (score 0):

To answer one part with the close button. A solution is to add the close button yourself (there is no option for that built in Swing).
You have to implement the `closeTab(…)` method or a better solution would be a callback handler

```java
protected class CloseTabButton extends JPanel {
    private JLabel            titleLabel;

    protected CloseTabButton(JTabbedPane aTabbedPane,
            final AbstractObservableObjectJPanel<M> aDetailPanel,
            String aTitle, Icon anIcon) {
        setOpaque(false);

        titleLabel = new JLabel(aTitle, anIcon, JLabel.LEFT);
        add(titleLabel);
        ImageIcon closeImage = new ImageIcon(
                CloseTabButton.class.getResource("/images/icon_normal.png"));
        Image img = closeImage.getImage();
        Image newimg = img.getScaledInstance(16, 16,
                java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
        ImageIcon closeIcon = new ImageIcon(newimg);

        ImageIcon closeImageRollover = new ImageIcon(
                CloseTabButton.class.getResource("/images/icon_roll.png"));
        Image imgRoll = closeImageRollover.getImage();
        Image newimgRoll = imgRoll.getScaledInstance(16, 16,
                java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
        ImageIcon closeIconRoll = new ImageIcon(newimgRoll);

        JButton btClose = new JButton(closeIcon);
        btClose.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(15, 15));

        add(btClose);
        btClose.setOpaque(false);
        btClose.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        btClose.setBorderPainted(false);

        btClose.setRolloverIcon(closeIconRoll);
        btClose.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent aE) {
                closeTab(aDetailPanel);
            }
        });
        aTabbedPane.setTabComponentAt(
                aTabbedPane.indexOfComponent(aDetailPanel), this);
    }

    public JLabel getTitleLabel() {
        return titleLabel;
    }
}
```

To add keyboard shortcuts you can add them to the input map via

```java
KeyStroke ctrlW = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_W,
        InputEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK);
getRootPane()
        .getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT)
        .put(ctrlW, disposeAction.getValue(Action.NAME));
```

`DisposeAction` is just an Action that also calls `closeTab(…)`